# How to adjoin a terminal object to a category such that each constant morphism factors through it

Tags: category-theory

Let $\mathbf{C}$ be any category. Is there a way to adjoin a terminal object $\ast$ to $\mathbf{C}$ such that each constant morphism factors through any terminal object, i.e., for each constant $f:A\rightarrow B$, $f$ factors as $f:A\rightarrow B = g\circ t_A: A\rightarrow \ast \rightarrow B$ for some $g$

A morphism $f:A\rightarrow B$ is constant if and only if for each $r,s:C\rightarrow A$, we have $f\circ r =f\circ s$.

Obviously this is not always the case, for easy counterexamples you may consider  pre-ordered classes with a maximum element, viewed as categories.

I have tried the following approach:
Let $\mathbf{C}$ be any category and define $\mathbf{D}$ to be the category with objects $Ob(\mathbf{C})\cup \{\ast\}$ and with morphisms, the morphisms of $\mathbf{C}$ together with 
$$\{t_D^\ast:D\rightarrow \ast\ |\ D\in Ob(\mathbf{D}) \}\ \ \mathrm{and}$$
 $$\{T_f:T\rightarrow B\ |\ \forall\mathrm{\ constant}\  f:A\rightarrow B \mathrm{\ in\ \mathbf{C}}\ \mathrm{and\ }\forall\ \mathrm{terminal\ objects\ } T \mathrm{\ in}\ \mathbf{D} :T_f\circ t_A^T=f  \},$$ where $t_A^T$ is the unique morphism from $A$ to $T$ where $T$ is a terminal object in $\mathbf{D}$, i.e., including $\ast$.

Since the morphisms between any two objects, $A$ and $B$ is a set, there can only be set many morphisms from $\ast$ or $T$ to $B$ for any $\mathbf{D}$-object $B$.

My problem arises in definining the composition and checking that this is in fact associative. Clearly $t_\ast = id_\ast$ and in order for any terminal object $T$ to remain terminal, $t_T$ must be an isomorphism. Also, $T_f \circ t_A^T=f$, but how could I define $g\circ T_f$ for some $g:B\rightarrow C$?

Is there a way to describe all the morphisms of $\mathbf{D}$ explicitly, or is there a better approach to generate a **smallest** category $\mathbf{D}$ that satisfies these properties and for which $\mathbf{C}$ is a subcategory?

Comment: It's not really obvious to me, but how would you define such a forgetful functor? Did you perhaps mean, a forgetful functor from $\mathbf{A}$ to $\mathbf{Cat}$?

Comment: Oups sorry, I meant $A\to Cat$ (the inclusion functor). I guess the question is whether the adjoint should be a morphism of 2-categories or something like that. That would depend on the properties you want for your construction.

Comment: Wouldn't that just amount to constructing such a category anyway?

Comment: Sure, it's not a solution, you still have to find a construction. It's just a way to state what property this construction should satisfy exactly if it exists (it gives a rigourous meaning to the word "minimal" in your question).

Comment: Yes, of course thank you.

Comment: Do you want the category $\mathbf D$ to have the property that every constant morphism in $\mathbf D$ factors through the terminal object of $\mathbf D$, or only that every constant morphism in the subcategory $\mathbf C$ factors through the terminal object of $\mathbf D$? If the former, then the sets of constant morphisms $A\to B$ in $\mathbf D$ depends only on $B$/are all isomorphic to the sets of constant morphisms $*\to B$, so in passing from $\mathbf C$ to $\mathbf D$ you will need to change the constant morphisms in all hom-sets, not just add morphisms $*\to B$.

Comment: @VladimirSotirov Thanks, that's a valid point, but maybe my question was a little bit ill stated. I have given it quite a bit of thought and in order for this to be useful to me, I need all constant morphisms in $\mathbf{D}$ to factor through a terminal object and have thought about this problem. I think I might have come up with a $3$ step construction for such a category $\mathbf{D}$. I'm pretty sure that it will be minmal among such categories as well, so that if $\mathbf{A}$ is another supercategory of $\mathbf{C}$, then there is a unique embedding from $\mathbf{D}$ to $\mathbf{A}$.